# How to Read Mails using Java or using any third party tools like ServiceMix

Tags: java, swing, email, gmail, apache-servicemix

I want to read mails from mail server. My mail server can be any server.
but when I study for this topic I found reading mail from gmail is easier option and Now i want to read mail from gmail.

My basic requirement is to skip the the HTML/TEXT mail and read only the TEXT mails.
I have found several API for this but now working for me.
I have also found Apache ServiceMix has mail reading component. Can i use this for my project or
What is the preferred way for me ?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: "I have found several API for this but now working for me" - It will be great if you can provide more details on *what* is not working and what all you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JavaMail to perform this operation and some examples can be found here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.3-oth-JPR

Comment: Above link is for JavaMail API download?
Actually I already downloaded JavaMail API. Please guide me with suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using Apache Camel.
Please refer http://camel.apache.org/mail.html for reference.